# Cannot unshare screen on zoom

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, kde, zoom-meeting

I seem unable to unshare my screen when using zoom.  There doesn't seem to be any menu option to do so.  When I google, all I can find are tips on how to share one's screen.  Anyone else know what has to be done to make this happen?  Zoom version 5.1; ubuntu 20.04

Comment: https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us That is the URL to the zoom help center. Best ask them.

Comment: @David fair enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by updating to the latest version of zoom.

Comment: Unfortunately, still not working with the newest version from the Zoom site

Comment: Indeed, same here. Zoom is freshly updated, however, sometime when I share my screen, there is no 'stop sharing' button. Also, the entire dropdown menu where you would find annotations and so on doesn't show, when I move the cursor to the top center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have hanged zoom process which can't stop screen sharing and hide time on the top with message "Stop Share Alt+S".
I solve this problem with killing them from console:

```
killall zoom
```